# How to setup IntelliJ to recognize Scala's "???" method as a TODO

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, notimplementedexception

I'd like to see all occurrences of `???` in the IntelliJ TODO list (or in any other way to be able to see a list of all unimplemented methods in my Scala project).
It seems adding the pattern **\b\?\?\?\b.*** in the TODO settings doesn't work.

Comment: I use two workarounds: 1) I always add a `TODO` comment after a `???`, describing in short words what needs to be done here. 2) Whenever I use `???` in the code, I always write a test case that fails because of the `???`. - If you use both of the suggestions, you can be pretty sure that you won't forget a `???`. Plus, you'll have a comment containing a bit more detail for your fellow developers, and a test case.

Answer (score 2):

Intellij allows you to create custom TODO patterns.

In your TODO window click on the filters icon > Edit Filters > Add new pattern.

Once you add a new pattern Intellij will rescan your project and add the new TODOs to the list.

[Official JetBrains TODO Example](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/todo-example.html)

**Update:**

As per comments, I did a quick test and it doesn't look like it's possible to scan for TODOs outside comments.

Comment: He already said that `\b\?\?\?\b.*` didn't work (which makes sense as I'd expect that those patterns are only looked for inside comments), so this does not seem helpful.